# Weird growth 24h after adding sugar for carbonation, is this normal?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, priming

I've finished coldcrashing this cream ale I've been brewing, I took some samples and they tasted great, so I've moved it to an airtight container and added sugar for carbonation. I checked it the next day and these weird tentacle looking things started growing on it. Could this be an infection starting or is it just the yeast doing yeasty things?

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK90g.jpg)
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHEIV.jpg)

Also, it doesn't seem to have released any CO2 yet, the pressure gague remains at 0.

Comment: I am afraid you have a contamination. I haven't seen something like this on my beers. What kind of contamination it is I don't know, that is why I only comment on this.

Comment: This just looks like coldbreak to me, although I don't usually see it later in the brew process. If the beer tastes fine I wouldn't worry, probably just some coagulated crud.